# Assign rows value to other sheet with column offset

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to assign a range value / entire rows from one sheet and offset the assignment by one row?

with code below, I can copy the Row but w/o Offset.

```
ws_To_See.Rows("1:2").Value = ws_New_Ver.Rows("1:2").Value
```

Comment: so you want them in rows 2 and 3 or do you want them in the next open row?

Comment: I suppose "2:3" is a too simple answer?

Comment: 2:3 would move to row 2...and 3

Comment: hey Scott, yep, it would be ideal to maintain in row 1 and 2 since they are considered headers

Comment: do you want to offset by a **row** or **column**? your title says one thing and your body another? And you can't `offset` and *entire row* by any amount of columns as this would be push the data off the sheet.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman, I understand your point...the idea is to "copy" a entire row assigning the cell/row. But it seems that rows can only be assigned directly as rows. Tried with a single cell as initial reference and only the first data referenced as the matrix of the rows was asssigned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to assign a range value / entire rows from one sheet and offset the assignment by one row?

**Yes**, you can perform a direct value transfer on entire rows to a destination that is [.Offset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840060.aspx) to the source either up or down until the offset is sufficient to push the destination off the worksheet.

```
'push the values from New_Ver!1:2 into To_See!6:7
ws_To_See.Rows("1:2").Offset(5, 0) = ws_New_Ver.Rows("1:2").Value
```

**No**, you **cannot** perform a direct value transfer on entire rows to a destination that is [.Offset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840060.aspx) to the source either left or right by any amount because that offset is (by strict definition) sufficient to push the destination off the worksheet.

```
'the destination here is a #REF! because it cannot exist on the destination worksheet
ws_To_See.Rows("1:2").Offset(0, 5) = ws_New_Ver.Rows("1:2").Value
ws_To_See.Rows("1:2").Offset(0, -5) = ws_New_Ver.Rows("1:2").Value
```

**However**, you can resize the source to fit the available number of cells in a resized destination that is offset to the right.

```
'the destination here is OK because the source has been resized to suit the column offset
'remember to Resize BEFORE Offsetting to avoid #REF!
ws_To_See.Rows("1:2").Resize(2, Columns.Count - 5).Offset(0, 5) = _
    ws_New_Ver.Rows("1:2").Resize(2, Columns.Count - 5).Value  '<~~ works!
ws_To_See.Rows("1:2").Offset(0, 5).Resize(2, Columns.Count - 5) = _
    ws_New_Ver.Rows("1:2").Resize(2, Columns.Count - 5).Value  '<~~ #REF!

'but you still cannot choose a destination to the left of column A
ws_To_See.Rows("1:2").Cells.Resize(2, Columns.Count - 5).Offset(0, -5) = _
    ws_New_Ver.Rows("1:2").Cells.Resize(1, Columns.Count - 5).Value  '<~~ #REF!
```

As noted in this last scenario, you must [.Resize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa176182%28v=office.11%29.aspx) *before* offsetting in order to maintain a valid worksheet cell range.